# Shortest word possible

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

In a give `context-free grammar language`

$L = \{z^{3x} y^i w^j \ |\ x \ge 0 \land  j \gt 2i \gt 0\}$

The shortest possible word that does not belong to the language would be $\lambda$.

But I'm having troubles to find the shortest work that does belong to the language.

`x` can be `0`. But the minimum value for `i` is `1`. Then the minimum value for `j` would be `2`. Leaving $y^1c^w$ = $yw^2$ =  yww.

Is my reasoning valid?

It's been a while since I studied this and I'm having troubles to find good resources to work this out.

Comment: You have $j > 2i$, so it must be at least $3$, and $3^0 = 1$, so the shortest possible word is `abccc`.

Comment: j>2i, means j should be 3 in your example

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer if you add it as an answer I can accept it for others in doubt.

Comment: Wait. I just saw the source. You wrote `{z^3}^x` there. Did you mean $\left(z^3\right)^x$ instead of the $z^{(3^x)}$ that one parses without parentheses? If that, then the choice $x = 0$ would indeed lead to `ywww` as the shortest word (and why did you change from `abc` to `zyw`, out of curiosity)?

Comment: @DanielFischer it is z^(3x) but looking at the help page I couldn't figure out a way to do that other than {z^3}^x. I changed it to make it the exact same example as the book I'm using to practice.

Comment: `z^{3x}` produces $z^{3x}$. I will adapt my answer then.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks again and sorry for making you change your answer.

Comment: No problem, it isn't a big change. If I had to rewrite "War and Peace", **that** would be inconvenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar requires a strict inequality $j > 2i > 0$, so there must be at least $3$ `w`s, <del>and since $3^0 = 1$, there must be at least one `z`. The shortest word in `L` is hence `zywww`, corresponding to the smallest possible choices, $x = 0,\, i = 1,\, j = 2i+1 = 3$.</del> The struck-out part refers to a mis-parsed grammar due to typesetting difficulties, the intended grammar $$\{ z^{3x}y^iw^j \mid x\geqslant 0 \land j > 2i > 0\}$$ does not require a $z$, hence the shortest word in $L$ is `ywww`, corresponding to $x = 0,\, i = 1,\, j = 2i+1 = 3$.